# Import bootstrap with stylus

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, stylus, brunch

I started up with [boilderplate](https://github.com/paulmillr/brunch-with-chaplin) for brunch. And now i want to include [bootstrap-styl](https://github.com/maxmx/bootstrap-stylus) here. I've installed bootstrap with npm, worked fine. Now it sits in **node_modules** folder. The problem appears when im trying to `@import bootstrap` in *.styl file.

```
failed to locate @import file bootstrap.styl
```

According to docs this is what i need to get this to work:

```
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap-styl'),
    stylus    = require('stylus');

function compile(str) {
  return stylus(str)
    .use(bootstrap());
}
```

So where exactly do i need to write this? In any of my scripts? I'm totally don't get how this hole thing works. Tried to put this code in empty script file, still no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The README for `stylus-brunch` does address that — https://github.com/brunch/stylus-brunch#use-plugin-middleware

In your case, you'd want to edit your `brunch-config` to have:

```
config =
  plugins:
    stylus:
      plugins: ['bootstrap-stylus']
```